# Crashday - getting Custom Car Pack 1 working

Tags: mods, crashday

Windows 7 64-bit.

Crashday is installed and patched to 1.1.

The Custom Car Pack seems to go through the motions of installing correctly but in the game I still have the same 12 cars. I'm using a 100% savegame off the internet also.

flatoutjoint.com seems to be the place to go for questions but it's down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it *was* installed properly - I had to go into multiplayer before the new cars 'kicked in' for some reason, and once I could see them I had to buy them in the shop.